# Process big size of file and memory management

Tags: c++, json, memory-management, nlohmann-json

I tried to read and parse (using nlohmann library) a `Json`  file that is almost `90MB` using this code:

```
std::ifstream ifs("data.json");
json jsonFile = json::parse(ifs);
```

The `Json` file to parse has almost **14000** array elements that need to be parsed.
when I run this code the memory usage for my program goes up till it reach `2GB` of memory! That is something very unexpected and huge for a small program like this.

How can I manage memory usage for this?
Is it better to get file data using other methods and then pass it to library?

Comment: @some programmer dude, well but not 2GB for a 90MB file...

Comment: @StefanRiedel probably depends on how `nlohmann` library handles the data, but maybe it is a bit huge memory consumption.

Comment: By the way, how to do check the memory usage? Even if the process have 2 GiB mapped to it, doesn't mean all that memory is actually used. The OS could reclaim it if needed.

Comment: nlohmann has a SAX (event-based) interface: https://nlohmann.github.io/json/features/parsing/sax_interface/ . SAX parsers are harder to write, but you can process a big file this way by processing the data piecemeal and not holding all the contents of the file in memory at once.

Comment: Aside, 90MB is not that big (multi-GB JSONs are not that uncommon), and nlohmann intentionally prioritizes ease of use over performance. A more efficient library like [sajson](https://github.com/chadaustin/sajson) or [simdjson](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson) might use less RAM when storing the same document.